# SQL getting people within 30 days of birthday (regardless of year)

Tags: sql-server

i am trying to get all employees whose birthday is coming up, It seems what i am trying to go isn't functioning properly because the year is being considered each time.

so the query i got now is

```
SELECT   [emp].[FirstName]
        ,[emp].[LastName] 
        ,[emp].[Birthday]
FROM [Employees] AS [emp]
WHERE [emp].[ID] != 12
    AND [emp].[Birthday] >= GETDATE() 
    AND [emp].[Birthday] <= DATEADD(dd,20,GETDATE())
```

the problem is no employees birthday is in 2016. any idea how i can check this

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   [emp].[FirstName]
        ,[emp].[LastName] 
        ,[emp].[Birthday]
FROM [Employees] AS [emp]
WHERE [emp].[ID] != 12
    AND MONTH([emp].[Birthday]) IN (MONTH(GETDATE()),MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,1,GETDATE())))
    AND DAY([emp].[Birthday]) >= DAY(GETDATE())
```

**UPDATE**

I didn't realize this could go this complex, The above query will not work if current date in number is greater than the birthday date in number (Ex: if current date is 29 and the birthday falls on 3rd of next month)

I tried following an updated version, so far it works good.

```
SELECT   [emp].[FirstName]
            ,[emp].[LastName] 
            ,[emp].[Birthday]
    FROM [Employees] AS [emp]
    WHERE [emp].[ID] != 12
AND ((MONTH([emp].[Birthday]) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY([emp].[Birthday]) > DAY(GETDATE()))
    OR (MONTH([emp].[Birthday]) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,1,GETDATE())) AND DAY([emp].[Birthday]) < DAY(DATEADD(MONTH,1,GETDATE()))))
```

So, the logic is:

`If` birthday month is `same` as current month, then date should be `greater` than current date

ELSE if birthday month is `current+1` month, then date should be `lesser` than next month date.

Answer (score 2):

Much simpler and cleaner:

```
    WHERE [emp].[ID] != 12
        AND DATEPART(dayofyear, [emp].[Birthday]) BETWEEN DATEPART(dayofyear, GETDATE()) AND DATEPART(dayofyear, GETDATE() + 30)
```

Comment: Doesn't work when today's date is less than 30 days from the end of the year.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or greater, you can use the [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) function to coerce your birthday dates into the current year:

```
SELECT   [emp].[FirstName]
        ,[emp].[LastName] 
        ,[emp].[Birthday]
FROM [Employees] AS [emp]
WHERE [emp].[ID] != 12
AND CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Birthday) = 2 AND DATEPART(DAY, Birthday) = 29 
        THEN DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()), 3, 1)
    ELSE 
        DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())+1, DATEPART(MONTH, Birthday), DATEPART(DAY, Birthday)) END 
BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(DAY, 30, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Does this work if the current date is at the end of the year and the Employee's Birthday is at the start?

Comment: i don't have that option. i must be using a lower version

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be prettier, but it won't get hung up when today is near the end of the year and there are birthdays at the beginning of the next year:

```
SELECT [emp].[FirstName]
      ,[emp].[LastName] 
      ,[emp].[Birthday]
FROM [Employees] AS [emp]
WHERE [emp].[ID] != 12
AND DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), DATEADD(yy, CASE WHEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, [emp].Birthday, GETDATE()), [emp].Birthday) < DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + DATEDIFF(yy, [emp].Birthday, GETDATE()), [emp].Birthday)) BETWEEN 0 AND 20
```